# how to design Hbase schema for high performance

Tags: performance, hbase

Are there any good suggestions for designing a good performance Hbase schema. For example: don't use too many columnFamily, since too many columnFamily would cause the read/write slow? Separate big columns with small size columns in different columnFamily? I highly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Anything by Lars George is worth a read on this topic.

Comment: Every design is depending on the question that you want to solve. There is no single solution for all the questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An HBase table is made of column families which are the logical and physical grouping of columns. The columns in one family are stored separately from the columns in another family. If you have data that is not often queried, assign that data to a separate column family.

The column family and column qualifier names are repeated for each row. Therefore, keep the names as short as possible to reduce the amount of data that HBase stores and reads. For example, use f:q instead of mycolumnfamily:mycolumnqualifier.

Because column families are stored in separate HFiles, keep the number of column families as small as possible. You also want to reduce the number of column families to reduce the frequency of MemStore flushes, and the frequency of compactions. And, by using the smallest number of column families possible, you can improve the LOAD time and reduce disk consumption.